# Display Stock Ticker for TXN

Tags: web-part

How do I put a Stock Ticker for TXN on your sharepoint page? It could be a free webpart or CEWP with jqury, java or html. Please suggest.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: This is awefully vague and could generate multiple correct answers, please refine your question to get a specific answer.

Comment: What's vague about it? A box containing stock price for a given ticker. I am looking for code to put it in CEWP or a web part that can take ticker and display respected information.

Comment: See my answer below. You can paste that script in a content editor and see if it works. Most likely you will want to customize the width,height, color, and the chart period, etc.., so visit the link I sent to customize your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a free one to use. You can plug this in the HTML of a content editor or somewhere on your master page. (Be sure to reference Jquery) (It is ready to show for TXN)

```
<script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/100840413740199312943/stock-quotes.xml&amp;up_stockList=TXN&amp;up_chart_bool=1&amp;up_font_size=12&amp;up_symbol_bool=0&amp;up_chart_period=0&amp;up_refresh_secs=30&amp;synd=open&amp;w=290&amp;h=300&amp;title=Stock+Quotes&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

You can further customize (width, height, color) the widget I sent above by [clicking HERE](http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/100840413740199312943/stock-quotes.xml&lang=en)

The problem is that with most free widgets and webparts, you will get a bunch of unnecessary ads and content.

For a clean widget, you will most likely need to pay for it. Below is a screen shot of the page that you can use to generate and customize your ticker.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the post. wish there was one without the AdChoice