# SharePoint Online - Display Stock Ticker

Tags: sharepoint-online, intranet, homepage

Just want to display stock price of my organization through Yahoo finance or other options on the home page of a site.

For example,

[image: MSFT]

Format is **MSFT - Price, up/down, %**. This should be a continuous feed and should get updated.

Please suggest all available options.

Comment: I could think of a webpart..

Comment: Which webpart, Sir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to put together a small POC which pulls stock price and also refreshes at a predefined time interval. Thic POC is created by referring to [jquery stockquotes](https://github.com/ajwhite/jquery-stockquotes) plugin.

Please add a content editor webpart to your page and paste the HTML code given below in it. Use the javascript code to create a JS file and upload it in some library. Do remember to update the JS file path in HTML otherwise it won't work.

Below is the code snippet for reference.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myStockCode.js"></script>
    <style>
    .StockName{font-size:1.5em;}
    .StockLastPrice{font-size:1.2em;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>Live Stock Price</h2>
    <br/>

    <div class="StockContainer">    
      <div class="StockName"></div>

      <span class="StockLastPrice"></span>
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+Cjxzdmcgd2lkdGg9IjI2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iMjZweCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI2IDI2IiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+CiAgPHBhdGggZD0iTTEyLjUsMyBMNCwxNSBMMTAuMjgwMjg1NywxNSBMMTAuMjgwMjg1NywyMi41IEwxNC43MTk3MTQzLDIyLjUgTDE0LjcxOTcxNDMsMTUgTDIxLDE1IEwxMi41LDMgTDEyLjUsMyBaIiBmaWxsPSIjM0Q5NDAwIj48L3BhdGg+Cjwvc3ZnPg==" alt="PriceUp" class="Up" style="display:none;">
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+Cjxzdmcgd2lkdGg9IjI2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iMjZweCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI2IDI2IiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+CiAgPHBhdGggZD0iTTEyLjUsMyBMNCwxNSBMMTAuMjgwMjg1NywxNSBMMTAuMjgwMjg1NywyMi41IEwxNC43MTk3MTQzLDIyLjUgTDE0LjcxOTcxNDMsMTUgTDIxLDE1IEwxMi41LDMgTDEyLjUsMyBaIiBmaWxsPSIjREQ0QjM5Ij48L3BhdGg+Cjwvc3ZnPg==" alt="PriceDown" class="Down" style="transform:rotate(180deg);display:none;">
      <span class="StockChange"></span>
      <span class="StockPercentChange"></span>
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript(myStockCode.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    getStockPrice();        
    setInterval(getStockPrice,5000);
  });

  var EndPoint = 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp';

  function getStockPrice () {
    return $.ajax({
      url: EndPoint,
      data: {symbol: "MSFT"},
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(function (response) {
        $(".StockName").text(response.Name);
        $(".StockLastPrice").text(response.LastPrice);
        $(".StockLastPrice").append("<sub>USD</sub>");

        if(response.Change<0)
        {
            $(".Down").show();
            $(".StockChange").css("color","red");
            $(".StockPercentChange").css("color","red");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".Up").show();
            $(".StockChange").css("color","green");
            $(".StockPercentChange").css("color","green");

        }
        $(".StockChange").text(Math.round(response.Change*100)/100);
        $(".StockPercentChange").text("("+Math.round(response.ChangePercent*100)/100+")");          
    });
  }
```

The end result looks like below:

[image]

Please let me know if it serves your purpose. You may need to update the CSS for better look and feel.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this, I don't expect this will be your final answer, but hopefully it will get you on the right path or help another user to find an answer for you. Create a new page, edit it and insert a web part.

When I edit my homepage I see we have a web part for a clock and weather.  You would like to have a stock ticker, but it's similar.

[image]

I actually have the clock_weather web part as what looks like a pre-installed web part option.  I imagine you would need to download a 'stock ticker app' and save it in the appropriate place in Sharepoint.  [This link](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-add-a-web-part-sharepoint-2013) might help a bit with doing that.

Once Sharepoint knows where to find your new stock ticker App, you would be able to edit your page to select the app and insert it as a web part in to your page.

[image: insert web part]

Your stock ticker app should be configurable from your Sharepoint page (this is the case with my weather_clock app in any case), I imagine your could configure the stock you wish to display.

[image: Configure app]

BTW - I am using SP 2013, I don't know whether that differs much to SP Online.

Additional research links:
[GitHub link](https://github.com/athrayee/StockQuoteWebpart)

One from [our beloved SP SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85565/display-stock-ticker-for-txn)

[Another instruction](https://www.rightpoint.com/thought/2014/02/25/how-to-display-stock-information-in-sharepoint-2013), detailed, using coding.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the REST endpoint.  You can add them inside a JS and use it masterpage or page layout.

Ideally get the stock information and save it in a [cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) with 5 min(based on your frequency) expiry time. Load data from there otherwise initiate a new call.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can add a Script Editor webpart in your website homepage, make a query to Yahoo Finance API & show the ticker. This [walkthrough](https://www.rightpoint.com/thought/2014/02/25/how-to-display-stock-information-in-sharepoint-2013) helps you.

On refreshing the content timely, you may have to use [setTimeout](http://itgroove.net/mmman/2011/05/16/adding-an-auto-refresh-content-editor-web-part/) to reload or reissue the web request.

Comment: Hello Arun, I believe Yahoo doesn't support YQL any more coz, when i Query it returns with a null value.

Comment: html table is no longer supported it seems pls use htmlstring. Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44431212/7920473

Comment: For Example, select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = "AXP". I am not passing a specific URL. How to implement it here?

Comment: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381291?tab=Overview

Here's a stock ticker that I built myself, I can give you an indefinite trial if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use ALPHA VANTAGE API to achieve it.

First, get the API key from here: https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key

Then use the API like this to get the json data.

**https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo**

**API Documentation**: https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/

Comment: Thanks @LZ-WX, This looks good, but it doesn't display the actual stock price. How to display the actual stock price?

Comment: Check ALPHA VANTAGE: https://www.alphavantage.co/

Comment: I like the JSON output, But can you please suggest, how should i display this JSON result on a page, and then have a continuous feed?  Like i have referred in the image.

Comment: you could implement web workers that update the webpart or script editor constantly: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

Comment: could this help, it's a link for RSS feeds: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bb2aa713-4bbb-442b-9904-4c35231f12c0/is-there-an-oob-way-to-show-a-companys-stock-ticker-nasdaq-in-a-sharepoint-web-part?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: Use "function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY", this API returns intraday time series (timestamp, open, high, low, close, volume) of the equity specified, updated realtime.

Comment: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381291?tab=Overview

This one has the stock prices, worth checking